# Custom Validation Message for numeric

Tags: validation

I want to Number validation for my site, but not able to show custom validation message to user.

```
       'CVV' => [
            'label'    =>  'CVV Number',
            'type' => 'numerical',              
            'numberPattern'=> '^[0-9]{3,3}$', 
            'min'   =>  100, 
            'minLength'   =>  3, 
            'max'   =>  999,
            'maxLength'   =>  3,
            'required' => true,
            'integerOnly'   =>  true,
            'tooSmall'  =>  'CVV Number is too small (minimum is 3 characters).',
            'message'  =>  'CVV Number is too small (minimum is 3 characters).',
            'tooShort'  =>  'CVV Number is too small (minimum is 3 characters).',
            'tooBig'  =>    'CVV Number is too long (maximum is 3 characters).',
            'tooLong'  =>    'CVV Number is too long (maximum is 3 characters).',                
        ],
```

I tried to set

```
AttributeType::Number
```

Also. But it didn't work.
**The issue:** 
in the case of numbers like less than 3 characters, I am getting error message:

```
CVV Number is too small (minimum is 100).
```

Please Can anyone help me to get this expected message.
Thank You.

Comment: Can you add some more context here? Is this a custom validator class you've written or is this in a `rules()` method on a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed above code and added the custom validation function for CVV Validation

```
public function validateCVV($attribute) {
    $value = $this->$attribute;
    if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}$/', $value)) {
        $message = Craft::t("Oops!  Try again with a valid CVV security code on the back of your card.");
        $this->addError($attribute, $message);
    }        
}

$rules[] = ['CVC', 'validateCVV'];
```

Thank You.